# How can I extract a specific section of a JSON string using a regex in Python?

Tags: python, json, string

so i have a string which looks like this (for example) :

```
{"e":"kline","E":1636631940480,"s":"EPSUSDT","k":{"t":1636631880000,"T":1636631939999,"s":"EPSUSDT","i":"1m","f":15980499,"L":15980734,"o":"0.56630000","c":"0.57200000","h":"0.57300000","l":"0.56630000","v":"280740.00000000","n":236,"x":true,"q":"159924.80310000","V":"150693.00000000","Q":"85802.85780000","B":"0"}}
```

I am trying to extract certain values from it, lets say i want regex to return `"c":"0.57200000"` or just the value of `0.57200000`.

I tried this code (at least to be able to get "c") but it gives me nothing :

```
re.search(r'^\"c\",$', resp) # resp is the string variable
```

Im new to regex and even after 2 hours of searching, im still unable to do it...

Comment: That isn't a string, that is dict, what variable type holds that ?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/eLfqQZ, this is a valid JSON.

Comment: @azro oh... weird because when i type (type(resp)) it returns <class 'str'>

Comment: That is because of how you paste it here, as you show what is printed we could thing that it's a dict, the better would be to show `'{"e":"kline","E":1636631940480,"s"...}'` **but** as there is only double quotes, and `true` (and not `True`) we know that it is a JSON sting

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew alright, now i understand, thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Your string is a valid JSON content, so load it as a python structure : `dict`, then access the data using the keys `k` and `c`

```
import json

value = '{"e":"kline","E":1636631940480,"s":"EPSUSDT","k":{"t":1636631880000,"T":1636631939999,' \
        '"s":"EPSUSDT","i":"1m","f":15980499,"L":15980734,"o":"0.56630000","c":"0.57200000",' \
        '"h":"0.57300000","l":"0.56630000","v":"280740.00000000","n":236,"x":true,' \
        '"q":"159924.80310000","V":"150693.00000000","Q":"85802.85780000","B":"0"}}'

value = json.loads(value)
print(value['k']['c'])  # 0.57200000
```

Comment: alright guys thanks it works now

Comment: Nice. If you don't know `c` is nested one could use `print(nested_lookup('c', json.loads(value))[0])`. Not sure if there is even any easier way.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to get some value from `dict` not string.

```
    dict = {"e": "kline", "E":1636631940480,"s":"EPSUSDT","k":{"t":1636631880000,"T":1636631939999,"s":"EPSUSDT","i":"1m","f":15980499,"L":15980734,"o":"0.56630000","c":"0.57200000","h":"0.57300000","l":"0.56630000","v":"280740.00000000","n":236,"x":True,"q":"159924.80310000","V":"150693.00000000","Q":"85802.85780000","B":"0"}}

print(dict["k"]["c"])
```

Comment: i dont know if im doing something wrong, but it returns "TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: You can add your code here that we can review it and see whats the problem?

Comment: Nevermind, i found the problem, your solution works as well ^^ thanks !